# Get delta of a counters for a specified period of time TransactSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's a simple table

```
DECLARE @SNH TABLE 
(
    cntDATE date, 
    cntQUEUE varchar(10),
    cntSHEETSTOTAL varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @SNH (cntDATE, cntQUEUE, cntSHEETSTOTAL)
VALUES ('2001-04-04', 'Queue01', 840),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue01', 850),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue01', 860)
```

Would someone propose a SQL request for getting delta of a counter for a period of time specified?
SQL request should take DATESTART and DATEEND as two parameters and produce a difference between cntSHEETSTOTAL

Comment: please post data as text not images

Answer (score 0):

this would be an answer

```
SELECT  D.cntQUEUE as 'queue',

    D.cntQUEUE as 'name', D.cntQUEUE as 'brand',
    F.cntDATE as 'date_first', L.cntDATE as 'date_last',  
    F.cntSHEETSTOTAL as 'total_first', L.cntSHEETSTOTAL as 'total_last', L.cntSHEETSTOTAL-F.cntSHEETSTOTAL as 'total_delta' 

 FROM 
    ( SELECT cntQUEUE, max(cntQGROUP) as 'qgroup', cntSERVER as 'server', min(cntTIMESLOT) as 'first', max(cntTIMESLOT) as 'last' FROM [dbo].[queuescounters] WHERE cntDATE>='2022-03-01T00:00:00.000' AND cntQGROUP='default' AND cntLEVEL=2 AND cntSNMP=1 GROUP BY cntSERVER, cntQUEUE ) AS D,
    queuescounters as F,
    queuescounters as L
 WHERE D.first != D.last AND F.cntLEVEL=2 AND F.cntQUEUE=D.cntQUEUE AND F.cntTIMESLOT=D.first AND L.cntLEVEL=2 AND L.cntQUEUE=D.cntQUEUE AND L.cntTIMESLOT=D.last ORDER BY D.qgroup, D.cntQUEUE
```